# Rake Setup - ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed:

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6, rake-task

In trying to run a setup rake tasks(to populate my dbase).   It is telling me that questions must exist.  When I do a count on 'Question.count' - it returns 4 - so I know questions exist.

What am I missing? typo?  syntax? When I look at similiar SO, it shows as some sort of typo but I am not seeing it.

Here is the code that is not working:

```
def add_option_group
  puts "  * Add Option Groups...\n"
  OptionGroup.transaction do
    create_option_group(
        option_group_name: "Always-Never", 
        question_id: Question.find_by(question_name: "Do you have an updated photo?")
    )
    create_option_group(
        option_group_name: "Yes-No", 
        question_id: Question.find_by(question_name: "Do you have a bio saved (updated in last 12 months)?")
    )
    end
end

def create_option_group(options={ })
  puts "  * CREATE OptionGroup Section...\n"

  option_group_attributes = {}
  attributes = option_group_attributes.merge options
  option_group = OptionGroup.create! attributes
  option_group.save!
  option_group
end
```

I am getting this error message:

- Add Option Groups...
- CREATE OptionGroup Section...
  rake aborted!
  **ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Questions must exist**
  /Users/axxx/workspace/fresh-assess/lib/tasks/setup.rake:314:in `create_option_group' /Users/axxx/workspace/fresh-assess/lib/tasks/setup.rake:298:in` block in add_option_group'
  /Users/axxx/workspace/fresh-assess/lib/tasks/setup.rake:297:in `add_option_group' /Users/axxx/workspace/fresh-assess/lib/tasks/setup.rake:51:in` create_sample_data!

Migration files:

```
    ***** migrations ******
class CreateOptionGroups < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :option_groups do |t|
      t.bigint :question_id
      t.text :option_group_name
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateQuestions < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :questions do |t|
 t.bigint :assessment_section_id
 t.bigint :input_type_id
 t.text :question_name
 t.string :question_subtext
 t.boolean :question_required_yn
      t.boolean :answer_required_yn
 t.boolean :allow_multiple_options_answers_yn
 t.integer :dependent_question_id
 t.integer :dependent_question_option_id
 t.integer :dependent_answer_id
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Here is schema

```
    t.bigint "question_id"
    t.bigint "option_choice_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "questions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "assessment_section_id"
    t.bigint "input_type_id"
    t.text "question_name"
    t.string "question_subtext"
    t.boolean "question_required_yn"
    t.boolean "answer_required_yn"
    t.boolean "allow_multiple_options_answers_yn"
    t.integer "dependent_question_id"
    t.integer "dependent_question_option_id"
    t.integer "dependent_answer_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end
```

Add foreign key:

```
class ForeignMoreKeysToModels < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    add_foreign_key :option_groups, :questions, validate: false
    add_foreign_key :option_choices, :option_groups, validate: false
  end
end
```

In the model:

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :assessment_section
    belongs_to :assessment_section, optional: true
    has_many :option_groups
end

class OptionGroup < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :option_choices
    belongs_to :questions
end
```

What am I missing?

thx.

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

1. In the `OptionGroup` class, it should say `belongs_to :question`.
2. Try adding `.id` to the question lookup:

```
create_option_group(
  option_group_name: "Always-Never", 
  question_id: Question.find_by(question_name: "Do you have an updated photo?").id
)
```